# Can I show public youtube live videos on my Android app?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have app which shows some live streams from youtube
I have taken permission for some channels to show their live streams on my app, but there are some other channells which I am not able to reach and they don't mention anything about copyright and else

If I show publicly open  Youtube Live Streams on my Android app would it cause to any problem?

If you inform me I will be glad

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As long as the livestreams are public and you aren't making money off of the app you are making, (Ads, Paid apps, etc.) you are allowed to use the livestreams.

Comment: is it writing in youtube conditions and terms sheet ?

Comment: @ARKA what do you mean

Comment: I mean is it written in YouTube rules?

Comment: @ARKA Yes. Also, if my answer was good, please upvote it or mark it as a solution with the little checkmark icon.